# How to use dynamodb.output.numParallelTasks in Glue?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-glue

We are using dynamodb.output.numParallelTasks in a Glue Job but we don't know exactly what it is doing or its main function.

Anyone have used it?

Answer (score 0):

Clearly defined in the documentation [Connection types and options for ETL in AWS Glue - AWS Glue](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/aws-glue-programming-etl-connect.html#aws-glue-programming-etl-connect-dynamodb):

> - `"dynamodb.output.numParallelTasks"`: (Optional) Defines how many parallel tasks write into DynamoDB at the same time. Used to calculate permissive WCU per Spark task. If you do not want to control these details, you do not need to specify this parameter.
>
>   - `permissiveWcuPerTask = TableWCU * dynamodb.throughput.write.percent / dynamodb.output.numParallelTasks`
>   - If you do not specify this parameter, the permissive WCU per Spark task will be automatically calculated by the following formula:
>
>     - `numPartitions = dynamicframe.getNumPartitions()`
>
>       - `numExecutors =`
>
>         - `(DPU - 1) * 2 - 1 if WorkerType is Standard`
>         - `(NumberOfWorkers - 1)` if `WorkerType` is `G.1X` or `G.2X`
>     - `numSlotsPerExecutor =`
>
>       - `4` if `WorkerType` is `Standard`
>       - `8` if `WorkerType` is `G.1X`
>       - `16` if `WorkerType` is `G.2X`
>     - `numSlots = numSlotsPerExecutor * numExecutors`
>     - `numParallelTasks = min(numPartitions, numSlots)`
>   - Example 1. DPU=10, WorkerType=Standard. Input DynamicFrame has 100 RDD partitions.
>
>     - `numPartitions = 100`
>     - `numExecutors = (10 - 1) * 2 - 1 = 17`
>     - `numSlots = 4 * 17 = 68`
>     - `numParallelTasks = min(100, 68) = 68`
>   - Example 2. DPU=10, WorkerType=Standard. Input DynamicFrame has 20 RDD partitions.
>
>     - `numPartitions = 20`
>     - `numExecutors = (10 - 1) * 2 - 1 = 17`
>     - `numSlots = 4 * 17 = 68`
>     - `numParallelTasks = min(20, 68) = 20`